# How to solve a compilation error (in code :: blocks) of a program already tested on other compilers

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I have a problem compiling with the IDE "Code::Blocks" after running a program already tested on android with "Cxxdroid - C ++ compile IDE for mobile development" that worked very well. This is what the compiler (mingw) of "Code::Blocks" shows:

> -------------- Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)------------>---
>
> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c >C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
>   mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\test.exe obj\Debug\main.o
>   C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp:18:7: warning: 'auto' changes meaning >in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
>    for (auto a : digits)
>         ^
>   C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp:18:12: error: 'a' does not name a type
>    for (auto a : digits)
>              ^
>   C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp:25:1: error: expected ';' before '}' >token
>   }
>   ^
>   C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp:25:1: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
>   C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp:25:1: error: expected ';' before '}' >token
>   C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp:25:1: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
>   C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp:25:1: error: expected ')' before '}' >token
>   C:\Users\amarn\Desktop\test\main.cpp:25:1: error: expected primary-expression before '}' token
>   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
>   7 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

And here is the program :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const string digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int main()
{
    ofstream f;
    f.open ("e.txt");
    for (auto a : digits)
    {
        f << a ;
        if (a == '1')

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I think the problem comes from the compiler, if it's the problem then which compiler should I install?

Comment: (that error occur when you don't have C++11. So see the question above for the solution)